# Chopped off openui5 drop down box

Tags: sapui5

```
timeDBox = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
        linebreak: true, 
        span: "L12 M12 S12"
    }),
    change: function(oEvent){
        //something
    }
});
```

which gives below box
[image]

But I want my drop down to be small so I changed

```
layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L4 M4 S4"}),
```

which is resulting chopped drop down
[image]

Any idea what's the issue with my code.

Comment: Why don't you use `width` property of the `DropdownBox` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `width` property while you define the control, no need for extra methods:

```js
var timeDBox = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
        linebreak: true, span: "L12 M12 S12"
    }),
    width: "40px",
    change: function(oEvent){
        //something
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timeDBox = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
                                            layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({linebreak: true, span: "L12 M12 S12"}),
                                            change: function(oEvent){
                                                //something
                                            }).setWidth("40px")
```

Adding setWidth to DropdownBox fixes the issue without changing the span.